# Autofill formula in the same row through the user specified number of columns

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded a macro to AutoFill a formula through `A5:D5`. However, instead of filling until P column every time, a macro should ask the user how many columns he/she wants to autofill the formula through. e.g. if user gives 6 columns, formula should fill through `A5:F6` and so on.

```
Range("A5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C<=R8C4,EDATE(RC[-1],1),"""")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A5:D5"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I tried doing this.

```
Dim myValue As Integer
myValue = InputBox("Enter number of months")
Range("A5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C<=R8C4,EDATE(RC[-1],1),"""")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A5:" & myValue & "5"),   Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your last line of code with:

```
 Range("A5").Resize(1,myValue).FillRight
```

In fact, you can probably replace your last 3 lines with this one line:

```
 Range("A5").Resize(1,myValue).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C<=R8C4,EDATE(RC[-1],1),"""")"
```